# Azure API Management not obtaining resource groups with service principal

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I created a service principal that obtains information (subscriptions, resource groups, and resources) from one of the organizations but not from others.

I have the following API Permissions in the Service principal (app reg)
Azure Service Management > user_impersonation
Dynamics CRM > user_impersonation

And I am using the [Azure API Management REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/)

The service principal is manually added to the Subscription with Reader role.

I wonder, do I need certain resource providers in the subscription?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> do I need certain resource providers in the subscription

*Yes, you need few [resource providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-services-resource-providers) should be registered in your Subscription which are:*

***`Microsoft.Resources`** - This resource provider is registered by default almost with any subscription because this resource provider is [Azure Resource Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/overview#consistent-management-layer)  which handles the REST APIs/Clients or Azure APIs requests.*

*As you mentioned that you're using Azure API Management Rest APIs, then you have to register another resource provider known as **`Microsoft.ApiManagement`** which you should register it manually.*